# How to know when something is pushed into a git repository

Tags: git

I'd like to know how to check if something is committed to a repository through git.
The idea is to take the committed files into a code review tool.

Comment: great, the git hook seems interesting and may do the work in a proper manner.
about the git count-objects, I was also thinking about the git describe command line, but I'm pretty new to git hence looking for advice about how to do that the cleanest way :-)

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a hook that pushes the new code into the code review tool: http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest would be to run git-count-objects and see when the number of objects increases.  Poll every 5 minutes or as you see fit.

```
$ git count-objects -v
count: 13
size: 568
in-pack: 48
packs: 1
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
```

"count" is unpacked, "in-pack" is packed, so "count"+"in-pack" should increase with a commit by at least one.

Or use a hook.

Comment: git count-objects only counts unpacked objects, so isn't reliable for something like this: if push sends enough objects, the server will just keep the pack.

Comment: And the -v flag will take care of that issue.

Comment: You could also poll `git rev-parse HEAD` and see if it changes